# Ring of all continuous functions from reals into reals is not integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be the ring of all continuous functions from the real numbers into the real numbers. Prove that $R$ is not an integral domain.

I need help with this. I do not understand this at all and my book really doesn't give that much information.

Answer (score 10):

A ring is an integral domain if it "has no zero divisors". i.e. if $a, b \in R$ and $ab = 0$ then $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

To show that your ring is not an integral domain, you need to find two continuous functions $f, g$ say that are not identically zero, but are such that $f(x)g(x) = 0 \space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(This is because the "zero" in this ring is the continuous function $h(x)$ such that $h(x) = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 8):

To prove $R$ is not an integral domain, all you need to do is find an example of zero divisors in $R$. A simple example is the following: $f,g\in R$ defined as
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x\in(-\infty,0)\\
x & x\in[0,\infty)
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
-x & x\in(-\infty,0)\\
0 & x\in[0,\infty).
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 4):

For example

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;x\le 0\\{}\\x&,\;\;x\ge 0\end{cases}\;\;\;,\;\;g(x)=\begin{cases}x&,\;\;x\le 0\\{}\\0&,\;\;x\ge 0\end{cases}$$