# Why are polynomials in $[0,1]$ not isomorphic to $C[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm learning about [Stone-Weisstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) and I learn that the closure of the polynomials is $C[0,1]$, I don't know where I read that they the polynomials in $[0,1]$ where isomorphic to $C[0,1]$. This only could happend if the polynomials in $[0,1]$ are closed but if I'm not mistaked they are not.

Comment: By isomorphic, do you mean isomorphic as rings under $+$ and $\times$?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, both answers help me a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they do not form a closed set. If they did, then the closure of the set $P$ of the polynomial functions from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb R$ would be $P$ itself, not $C[0,1]$, and the Stone-Weierstrass theorme would be false.

If you want a concrete example, consider the polynomials $P_n(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$. They converge to the exponential function in $C[0,1]$, and that function is not polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

The space of polynomials has countable infinite dimension (a basis is given by the $x^n$), while the space of continuous functions has uncountable infinite dimension.

The ring of polynomials is an integral domain, while the space of continuous functions is not (see for example [Ring of all continuous functions from reals into reals is not integral domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313473/ring-of-all-continuous-functions-from-reals-into-reals-is-not-integral-domain) - you can easily adopt this to $[0,1]$).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the isomorphism claim, or even what type of isomorphism is meant here: purely algebraic, an isometry in normed spaces (and if so, in what norm), etc..

In the sup norm, the polynomials do form a dense subset of ${\cal C}[0,1]$, by Stone-Weierstrass.  However, as you remarked, this set is not closed, and I think it even has no interior points.

To prove the absence of interior points, pick a polynomial $p(x)$ and an $\epsilon > 0$.

Now define $f_{\epsilon}(x) = 1 + {\epsilon} \;$([triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave)).

And, finally, let
$$
g(x) = f_{\epsilon}(x) p(x).
$$
Notice that $g$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, but is not a polynomial because of the cusps.  Intuitively, $g$ was constructed by taking $p(x)$ and "perturbing it with small-height cusps".

We see that
$$
|g(x) - p(x)| = {\epsilon} \; |\mbox{(triangle wave)}(x)| \leq {\epsilon}
$$
It follows that $p(x)$ has no open neighborhood consisting entirely of polynomials.